# Java - RestTemplate syntax error?

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, spring-boot

So I've got this controller method, which is obviously returning a ResponseEntity:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="sendEmail")
    public ResponseEntity sendPasswordResetEmail (@RequestParam("name")     final String name,
                                       @RequestParam("password") final String password,
                                       @RequestParam("email")    final String email)
{
            final boolean success = notificationService.sendPasswordResetEmail(name, password, email);
            return success ?
                    new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK) : new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

My problem is that when calling the following, it is not letting me set ResponseEntity.class as the third parameter, which does not makes sense because that is the expected returning type:

```
ResponseEntity<String> auth = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, ResponseEntity.class);
```

Any hint?

**UPDATE:**

How is it possible that the code compiles and runs and I get this when consuming the endpoint?

```
{
  "timestamp": 1444927133682,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
  "message": "org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/api/model/postmark/ResetPassword",
  "path": "/v1/api/notify/sendPasswordResetEmail"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the [`postForEntity`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForEntity-java.net.URI-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-) method you are attempting to use is

> ```
> public <T> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(URI url,
>                                        Object request,
>                                        Class<T> responseType)
>                                 throws RestClientException
> ```

In other words, it's always going to return a `ResponseEntity`. What you are providing as an argument is the type of the response body, which will tell the `RestTemplate` how to deserialize the content.

Simply use

```
ResponseEntity<String> auth = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks man. Still not working (it's throwing me a 400 BAD REQUEST) but at least the syntax error is gone.

Comment: This is what I am getting: '{
  "timestamp": 1444927133682,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
  "message": "org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thortful/api/model/postmark/ResetPassword",
  "path": "/v1/api/notify/sendPasswordResetEmail"
}'

Comment: @stackpepe If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, will do it in a new one, I've just updated it btw

Comment: @stackpepe No. I mean a new Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I know what you meant. I was updating the question while you wrote that comment.